# convert a docx file into pdf file using unoconv

Tags: docx, libreoffice, unoconv, docx-to-pdf-conversion

convert a docx file into pdf file using unoconv. It's taking too long to convert as pdf and aborted

**DOCX to pdf conversion command:**

```
 unoconv -f pdf -o sample.pdf sample.docx
```

[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/4cabff5hqm4pisgsmxbnz/QL2877BC-0522-CCM-BC-Satisfaction-Survey_final-copy.docx?dl=0&rlkey=75t6mr9lpqwfhz9hzr91ubj6m) the sammple docx file

Comment: convert a docx file into pdf file using unoconv. It's not converting. Can any one help me?

Comment: Try removing the "-o sample.pdf" from the command line

Comment: did this get resolved? I am trying the same

Comment: @SCramphorn This is not resolved. Could you please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Unfortunately I want the reverse, load PDFs into Libra and save as Word - i have around 2000 files...